# Does the single number matrix exist or is it a scalar.

Tags: matrices

Hello I just started learning about matrices, I am currently going through inverse of a matrix and I was wondering is the matrix like this $[a]$, with one row and one column a matrix or is it a scalar? And as such is the matrix $[1]$ a identity matrix or not?

Comment: Yes you can think of scalars as $1x1$ matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, there's nothing wrong with having $1\times 1$ matrices.

In practice, they are not really needed, since they behave *exactly* like scalars. Basically, that's because all $1\times 1$ matrices are scalar multiples of the identity matrix $[1]$.

So usually, we don't really deal with $1\times 1$ matrices, because they are too simple. They all have the same eigenvectors, their eigenvlues are trivial, there's really nothing interesting to do with them. But they're useful for some counterexamples.

Comment: but a $1 \times 1$ matrix will have more restrictions than scalar. I mean it could be multiplied only by matrices that have either one row or one column?

Comment: @Pawel Yes, of course. $1\times 1$ matrices are fundamentally different objects than scalars. But multiplication, addition, and inverses all work the same way on them than on scalars.

Comment: Great, I just want to know do they exist, because they are not mentioned in my textbook and the only reference online I could find to single matrices compare them with scalars, which did not seems completely true. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @Pawel Well, if the textbook talks about $n\times m$ matrices, that means it also talks about $1\times 1$ matrices :). But as I said, they usually aren't interesting to study.